# get model id in YII before saving the model

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

Before go to my question, please look at my controller first.

this is my controller:

```
public function actionTambahKnowledge(){
    $model = new Dokumen;

    if(isset($_POST['Dokumen']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Dokumen'];
        if($model->validate()){

            if(Yii::app()->vsm->preprocessing_kata($model->id)){ //LINE X
                $model->save(false)

                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('tambahknowledge','Knowledge baru berhasil ditambahkan');
                $this->redirect(array('tambahKnowledge'));

            }
        }
    }
     $this->render('tambahKnowledge',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

In `LINE X`, I want to get the model ID for `Yii::app()->vsm->preprocessing_kata` method. But, I only know that `$model->id` can be generated after `$model->save` is executed. In here, I want to save the model if the method in `LINE X` has been successfully executed. The method will return `true` if the method was success.

I have an alternative solution:
In order to get the model ID, so I have to query the latest ID in the model database, and use it to the method. BUT I'm afraid if there is someone else who access the `actionTambahKnowledge`in same time. So the model ID that retrieved from the database become unconsistent. For example, Mr.X access the `actionTambahKnowledge`. I Assume that Mr.X has a model ID that equals to `1`. But in same time, Mr.Y access the action too and Mr.Y get the same ID because Mr.X is not save the action yet. finally, Mr.X was successed to save the model and the method with the right model ID. Mr.Y was also successed save the model and the method, but the data that Mr.Y fill will replace the data from Mr.X.

So, can I get the model ID without saving the model? and How I can save the model and the method with right model ID even if there is a someone else who access the action in same time?

thanks and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not any way for accessing model id before saving it. But you can save your model inside a **transaction** first, then check your condition and if was not true, rollback the transaction:

```
$transaction=$model->dbConnection->beginTransaction();
$model->save(false);
if(Yii::app()->vsm->preprocessing_kata($model->id))
   $transaction->commit();
else
   $transaction->rollBack();
```